# El significado de usar una frase con "en" después del verbo "sentir"

Tags: traducción, gramática, uso-de-palabras, verbos, preposiciones

En esta frase: La fuerza de combate de un supersaiyano de tercer nivel es tan apabullante que llega a sentirse incluso en un lugar tan lejano como el Kaioshinkai.

Cuando dice que el fuerza apabullante se puede sentir "en el Kaioshinkai", gramatical/semánticamente, ¿se refiere a que el poder está en ese lugar, o solo se refiere a alguien que haría la acción de sentir el poder que está en ese lugar?

Por ejemplo, en inglés, una frase como "sentir en", "ver en", "escuchar en", gramatical/semánticamente, se referiría a la ubicación del objeto de esos verbos.

Answer (score 2):

No me queda muy clara cuál es tu pregunta ni en qué se diferencia el español del inglés en este caso.

Déjame simplificar un poco tu frase original para quitar elementos superfluos en relación a tu pregunta

ANTES

> La fuerza de combate de un supersaiyano de tercer nivel es tan
> apabullante que llega a **sentirse** incluso **en** un lugar tan lejano como
> el Kaioshinkai.

AHORA

> La fuerza se **siente en** el Kaioshinkai

Dado que un lugar no es capaz de sentir aquí encontramos un tropo lingüistico denominado [sinécdoque](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin%C3%A9cdoque)

> En la literatura lingüística, la sinécdoque es el tipo de tropo en que
> o bien el continente o bien el contenido representa al otro en una
> frase, tomando su lugar. Es decir, hay dos tipos de sinécdoque:
>
> 1. 'El
>    todo por la parte': "Colombia ha jugado bien" por "el equipo de fútbol
>    masculino de Colombia que ha alineado hoy el entrenador ha jugado
>    bien".
> 2. 'La parte por el todo': "Danos hoy nuestro pan de cada día" por "danos el alimento necesario de cada día"; "en esta familia hay cinco bocas que alimentar"; "el cabeza de familia"; “Vino” o “cerveza” por “bebida alcohólica”.

He pegado la definición completa pero en tu caso nos encontraríamos con el primer tipo de sinécdoque: el todo por la parte.

Cuando se dice

> La fuerza se **siente en** el Kaioshinkai

queremos decir

> La fuerza la sienten todos aquellos capaces de sentir fluctuaciones de fuerza de supersayanos que están localizados en Kaioshinkai

No hay información en la frase sobre el origen de la fuerza, más allá de que está situado en un lugar lejano respecto a Kaioshinkai. Este tropo no es específico del verbo **sentir** y la preposición **en**. Ni en español ni en inglés.

Answer (score 0):

- Se puede escuchar **en** la esquina.
- Se puede ver **en** la patagonia.
- Se puede sentir **en** los huesos.

Son expresiones que generalmente se usan para exagerar, **en** en este contexto se refiere a un lugar hasta donde dura la accion.

---

Une mejor expresion

> La fuerza del super Supersaiyan 3 es impresionante que incluso llega a
> sentirse **en** un lugar tan lejano como el Kaioshinkai.

---

The same word in English

> I feel it **in** my bones

Comment: Although interesting that does not seem directly related to the question. Can you edit it to make it more relevant?